# Sit at the bottom of the room?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Are any of these correct? I mean I used to sit on the one of the chairs farther from the teacher/front of the room.

I used to sit **at the bottom** of the room.
or
I used to sit **in the bottom** of the room.

Answer (score 1):

> I mean I used to sit on the one of the chairs farther from the teacher/front of the room.

Using the same verbiage in your examples, I believe the phrase you're looking for is:

> I used to sit **in/at the back** of the room.

The use of *bottom* suggests elevation, such as how *high* or *low* something may be from the *floor* of the room, and is why it shouldn't be used in this case.